# Is Restoring a previous backup results to happen bug again

Tags: restore

I am using Xiaomi phone, in which I have got a hardware error(sound problem), which may be a bug. Then I serviced my phone. Now it functions well.
If I **restore my previous backups**, should it result a hardware error again?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No backups are not connected to hardware problems. Hardware means physical part/s of the device. The backup is software, by that I mean the non-physical part (or correctly data).

If you want detailed, please write us what was the problem with you phone. What did the service sad about the problem.

Comment: On updating a developer version of android os, it may contain bugs. For example, camera app, while opening it, it  suddenly closes. So, installing the same version again can cause the same app error.

Comment: And again it's software bug,not hardware.
By the way, if it's newest bug, there should be an update in short period of time, if it's reported by users.
 If your device is rooted, I would suggest to install a ROM with best reviews and ratings.